# Moving email setting to web config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am try to move my email settings to web config, but i don't know how to call the setting from web config.

This is my newpassword web-config setting:

```xml
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="&quot;testo&quot; &lt;admin@test.com&gt;" >
      <network host="mail.test.com" userName="admin@test.com" password="waiff75E-" port="25"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

And this is my previous code

```
const string username = "test@smartguroo.com";
const string password = "password";
SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
MailAddress fromaddress = new MailAddress("admin@test.com", loggedinUser.Text + "test");
smtpclient.Host = "mail.test.com";
smtpclient.Port = 25;
mail.From = fromaddress;
mail.To.Add(userEmail.Text);
mail.Subject = ("New post on your wall from " + loggedinUser.Text + " ");
// mail.Attachments.Add(new mail);
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Body = "";
```

Comment: If you're specifying all settings in web.config. Again no need set in code. Check this for web.config - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164242%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following lines lines since you want your settings in the `web.config` file to drive it from the configuration point of view.

```
smtpclient.EnableSsl = false;
smtpclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
smtpclient.Send(mail);
```

And just call the Send method on the `SmtpClient`

```
smtpclient.Send(mail);
```

All the previous concerns are configured into your web.config file, as you have done so. (Copied verbatim)

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="&quot;testo&quot; &lt;admin@test.com&gt;" >
      <network host="mail.test.com" userName="admin@test.com" password="password" port="25"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: thanks, how do i remove the email from the C# code and call it from the web config

Comment: @Jack I've updated the answer to elaborate on the details. In summary, do not try to override the details of your `SmtpClient` via C# code; defer it to the `web.config` file to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

**In your webconfig**

```
 </connectionStrings>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
      <!-- Markup removed for clarity. -->

      <add key="mailAccount" value="xyz" />
      <add key="mailPassword" value="password" />
   </appSettings>
  <system.web>
```

**Reference in c# via**

```
  var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
             ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
             ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
             );
```

This was using [this identity tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset)